# Array search returns a new empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Below is my code with a search input hoos and I can't identify why it isn't working.

```
import Herois from './json/videos.json'

function App() {
  const [valueInput, setValueInput] = useState('')
  const [newArray, setNewArray] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const results = Herois.filter((i) => {
      i.title.toLowerCase().includes(valueInput.toLowerCase())
    })
    
    setNewArray(results)
    console.log(newArray)
  }, [valueInput])
}
```

is always becoming an empty array

Comment: console.log(results) ta mostrando algo?

Comment: @matmahnke - after update that was suggested below, Returns a value if I give console.log in the results, if I give console.log in newArray it returns empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const results = Herois.filter((i) => {
 // you have to return the something here
 return i.title.toLowerCase().includes(valueInput.toLowerCase())
})
```

or

```
const results = Herois.filter((i) => (i.title.toLowerCase().includes(valueInput.toLowerCase())
 ))
```

Comment: Returns a value if I give console.log in results, if I give console.log in newArray it returns empty

Comment: `setNewArray` is an async function means it will not block the next piece of code(`console.log(newArray)`) until it finishes executing. if you want to test newArray empty or not use this: `setTimeout(()=>{console.log(newArray)},1000)`